# Can I get better performance out of this linq query?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a form that when I load I populate with open invoices (85,000+ records).  The user has the ability to select "closed" invoices, which I default my daysOld combobox with 60.  (This allows me to perform a background task that retrieves all of the closed invoices that are within the past 60 days (100,000+ records).  The user can then select `60, 120, 360, 540, 720` from the drop down list.  If the user selects `720` I will rerun the query and return all of the closed invoices for the last 720 days (3.2million records).  However, if the user selects one of these higher number of days, and then re-selects a smaller day (60 for example) I don't want to rerun the query, I want to extract the data I need from the recordset I already have.

`_taClosed` is a list (of object) that I return based on the number of days selected.

```
Dim tot = (From tak In _taClosed
          Where tak.DateOfInvoice > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1 * cmbDaysOld.SelectedItem)).CopyToDataTable()
```

Please note it takes 5 seconds to run the linq query, which seems like a long time.  Any suggestions on increasing the performance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the time it takes has less to do with LINQ and all about the volume of data.

Comment: Does the query itself take 5 seconds or does it include the other operation does (i.e. CopyToDataTable) ? What is the state of your index?

Comment: @TMcKeown  I thought it might be the amount of data I was looking at, but I wasn't sure if the linq was set up correctly, in the most efficient way.

Comment: @SimonBelanger with the copyToDatatable it takes 5 seconds to run.

Comment: The query isn't doing anything other than a single date compare, this is data volume.

Comment: @JohnJanssen I missed the point where it says it is LINQ to object. Try moving your `DateTime.Now.AddDays` bit outside of the linq expression. I suspect the calculation is happening for every objects. It might improve a bit, but it is not the bulk of the operation.

Comment: @SimonBelanger thanks for the suggestion, it has improved performance dramatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I see is `DateTime.Now.AddDays()` call within lambda expression. You should calculate it only once, before entering the query:

```
Dim dateFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1 * cmbDaysOld.SelectedItem)
Dim tot = (From tak In _taClosed
          Where tak.DateOfInvoice > dateFrom).CopyToDataTable()
```

But I don't think it will make much of a difference.

With that many records you should consider using a database, instead of in-memory collection.

Also, are you showing all the items at once? There is no point in retrieving all the records when you only show several (because of pagination).

Comment: I have actually seen this kind of modification make a big difference in a linq query (moving the work out of the lambda if it can be done beforehand).  That said, the work I was doing in the lambda was string manipulation which is probably more intense than modifying your DateTime.

Comment: It will make a difference, but I'm not sure how big it will be.

Comment: This did make a huge difference, instead of the linq taking 5 seconds it takes 1 second.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With 3.2 million records, my suspicion is that the original data store will be quicker at searching that an in memory linq query.

I would question why are you loading that much raw data into a view in the 1st place. There is not practical way that a user can read through that much data.

Your query may simply be better written to load an aggregate view of the data and present that to the user.

Comment: I have a filter row on my ultrawingrid that I allow the user to filter the data.  I myself and my manager believe that we are returning too much data, but our users insist they need it.  We originally had 60 days worth of data, but there was information that wasn't showing up that our users needed, so we gave them this option.  I have implemented the other suggestion and it has dramatically improved performance.  Thank you for the suggestion.